# Expressing $G_{m,m+1}^{m+1,0}\left(x\middle| \begin{array}{c}1,\cdots,1 \\0,0,\cdots,0\\\end{array}\right)$ as a power series.

Tags: power-series, special-functions, residue-calculus, hypergeometric-function

I have this family of MeijerG functions:
$$
G_{m,m+1}^{m+1,0}\left(x\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,\cdots,1 \\
 0,0,\cdots,0 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)
$$
which I'd like to express in terms of a power series in $x$, eventually generalized hyper-geometric functions.

Does anyone knows how this can be done for this specific case?

Thanks.

---

Here are the first 3 elements of the family in **Mathematica** syntaxe:

```
MeijerG[{{}, {1}}, {{0, 0}, {}}, x]
MeijerG[{{}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0 }, {}}, x]
MeijerG[{{}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {}}, x]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the expansion around zero. We have
$$G_{m, m + 1}^{m + 1, 0}
 {\left( x \middle| {\mathbf 1 \atop \mathbf 0} \right)} =
\frac 1 {2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \Gamma(s) s^{-m} x^{-s} ds.$$
The sum of the residues over the simple poles at the negative integers gives a hypergeometric series:
$$\operatorname*{Res}_{s = -k} \Gamma(s) s^{-m} x^{-s} =
(-k)^{-m} x^k \,[(s + k)^{-1}] \,\Gamma(s) =
(-1)^m \frac {(-x)^k} {k^m k!}, \\
\operatorname*{Res}_{s = 0} \Gamma(s) s^{-m} x^{-s} =
[s^m] \,\Gamma(s + 1) e^{-s \ln x} =
\sum_{k = 0}^m
 \frac {\Gamma^{(k)}(1)} {k!} \frac {(-\ln x)^{m - k}} {(m - k)!}, \\
G_{m, m + 1}^{m + 1, 0}
 {\left( x \middle| {\mathbf 1 \atop \mathbf 0} \right)} =
\operatorname*{Res}_{s = 0} \Gamma(s) s^{-m} x^{-s} -
(-1)^m x \,{_{m + 1}\hspace{-2px}F_{m + 1}}(\mathbf 1; \mathbf 2; -x).$$